# Dual booting on a laptop with SSD and HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I saw a couple similar questions but they are pretty old (from win7 time) and I wanted to get an up-to-date answer.

I'm going to buy a new laptop with a 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD. I would like to dual boot both Windows10 and Ubuntu (or possibly Mint). Would the SSD be large enough to handle all windows and linux system files? My goal is to install both OSs on the SSD so it will boot fast and then use the HDD as overflow storage once the SSD starts filling up. How should I go about partitioning everything? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Although this question is asking for answers which are primarily opinion based, the official documentation does state that you only need a certain amount of partitioned space for your installed operating system.

With that said, you should certainly have enough space.

I recommend you use 2/3 of the total disk space for the OS you plan to use the most, including any swap partition if the OS uses swap.

Comment: That's an opinion, not fact.  Facts are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/ch03s04.html) and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications)  but that's not an answer, that's a comment.  **-1** and delete vote cast.

Comment: I think this is an answer, but you could improve it by adding the figures you mention existing in official documentation...